# Как запустить функцию после окончания другой функции?

Tags: javascript

У меня есть вот такая функция

```
<script>
$('#two_categor_mess').click(function () {
var feedback = 'hello';
$('.message-screen').append('<div class="user_two_message col-xs-12 col-sm-12"><div class="sender-text"><p>Please tell us about PatShop and PatStudio</p></div></div>');   
$('.delivered').addClass('old');
        $('.patshop_bot').addClass('old');
        $('.message-screen').append('<div class="delivered"><span>Delivered</span></div>');
   setTimeout(function() { 
   {
        setTimeout(function() {
            $('.message-screen').append('<div class="user_two_message col-xs-12 col-sm-12"><div class="received-text"><p>'+feedback+'</p></div></div>');
            $('.typing_block').hide();
  },1000)
        $('.delivered').addClass('old');
        $('.message-screen').append('<div class="delivered"><span>Read</span></div>');
        $('.message-screen').append('<div class="user_two_message col-xs-12 col-sm-12"><div class="typing_block"></div></div>');
    }
   }, 500);  
  });  
</script>
```

Она должна выполняться, если в этой функции выполняется условие else

```
$('#send').on('click', function () {
    setTimeout(function() { 
     var divValue = $('.sender-text').last().text();
    var test = 'hello';
    var feedback = 'hello ';
    var feedbackhowareyou = 'good ';
    var feedbackalret = ' Im sorry  Im in development and dont understand some of the messages.  Here are the questions I can help you with: ';
    var selectcategories = '<div class="swiper-container"><div class="swiper-wrapper"><div class="swiper-slide" id="first_categor_mess"><p>What is PatShop and PatStudio?</p></div><div class="swiper-slide" id="two_categor_mess"><p>How to add your project</p></div><div class="swiper-slide" id="last_categor_mess"><p>How to buy the project</p></div></div></div>';
    var selectcategoriestext = 'Choose one of the categories';


    if (divValue.indexOf(test) >= 0)
    {
        setTimeout(function() {
            $('.message-screen').append('<div class="user_two_message col-xs-12 col-sm-12"><div class="received-text"><p>'+feedback+'</p></div></div>');
            $('.typing_block').hide();
  },1000)
        $('.delivered').addClass('old');
        $('.message-screen').append('<div class="delivered"><span>Read</span></div>');
        $('.message-screen').append('<div class="user_two_message col-xs-12 col-sm-12"><div class="typing_block"></div></div>');
    }

    else {
        setTimeout(function() {
            $('.message-screen').append('<div class="user_two_message col-xs-12 col-sm-12"><div class="received-text"><p>'+feedbackalret+'</p></div></div>');
//            $('.message-screen').append('<div class="user_two_message col-xs-12 col-sm-12"><div class="received-text"><p>'+feedbackalrettwo+'</p></div></div>');
            $('.message-screen').append('<div class="user_two_message col-xs-12 col-sm-12">'+selectcategories+'</div>');
            $('.message-screen').append('<div class="user_two_message col-xs-12 col-sm-12"><div class="received-text"><p>'+selectcategoriestext+'</p></div></div>');
            $('.typing_block').hide();
  },1200)
        $('.delivered').addClass('old');
        $('.message-screen').append('<div class="delivered"><span>Read</span></div>');
        $('.message-screen').append('<div class="user_two_message col-xs-12 col-sm-12"><div class="typing_block"></div></div>');
};
        }, 500);
  });  
</script>
```

Код правильный, через браузерную консоль работает

Answer (score -1):

Добавил `onclick=MyFunction()` для блока